# Javascript: Trying to access elements of a JSON array gives me individual characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_cards.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {selection:JSON.stringify(selection)},
    success: function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        sessionStorage.setItem("json", JSON.stringify(json));
    }
});
```

Then, in another file I am retrieving the JSON from sessionStorage:

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem("json")));
if(json) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("json");
}
```

This gives me an array of JSON objects, example: `[{'name':'Bob',...}]`. However, when I try to access the first element of the array: `json[0]`, I get `'['` and when I try `json[0].name` I get `undefined`. The length of `json` is reported as 159, so it is counting each individual character as an element.

EDIT: When I update to:

```
var json = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("json"));
if(json) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("json");
}
```

I get a length of 1 (which is correct), but an error when accessing `json[0].name`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (studying.js:10)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: You have a string. Use `JSON.parse()` correctly

Comment: why are you stringifying it just to parse it again?

Comment: You are already saving the json string in local storage, Why are you calling stringify twice ?

Comment: You are stringifying an already stringified value when you get the value..

Comment: You stringified it twice. You don't need to re-stringify it after you pull it out of storage.

Comment: re: edit - What does `console.log(json);` show?

Comment: it's null, because there is no "json" item in `sessionStorage`. `JSON.parse(null)===null;`--->true

Answer (score 9):

You are stringifying the already stringified json:

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem("json"))); // wrong !
```

this should be:

```
var json = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("json"));
```

If you `JSON.stringify("foo")`, then you got a quoted string:`"\"foo\""`.

> `JSON.stringify()` converts a value to JSON notation representing it:
>
> - Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified
>     in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within
>     the same object within the stringification.
> - `Boolean`, `Number`, and
>     `String` objects are converted to the corresponding primitive values
>     during stringification, in accord with the traditional conversion
>     semantics.
> - If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during
>     conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or
>     censored to null (when it is found in an array). JSON.stringify can
>     also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like
>     JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).
> - All
>     symbol-keyed properties will be completely ignored, even when using
>     the replacer function.
> - Non-enumerable properties will be ignored
>
> **examples :**
>
> ```
>  JSON.stringify({});                  // '{}'
>  JSON.stringify(true);                // 'true'
>  JSON.stringify('foo');               // '"foo"'
>  JSON.stringify([1, 'false', false]); // '[1,"false",false]'
>  JSON.stringify({ x: 5 });            // '{"x":5}'
> ```

[Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: though it's just redundent code like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem("json")));` but stringify a string and after that parsing it to json make it's value string? how come?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi: You always get back the original value. And the original value (`sessionStorage.getItem("json")`) is a string. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("foo")) === "foo"`. *"parsing it to json"* Nothing is parsed *to* JSON. `JSON.stringify` *creates JSON*. `JSON.parse` creates a native JavaScript value from JSON. If a string value was encoded as JSON, you get a string value. If a number value was encoded as JSON, you get a number value. If an array was encoded as JSON you get an array, etc.

Comment: @FelixKling you are awesome

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi because when you run a stringified json object through `JSON.stringify` again, it does things like escape the quotes. So when you parse it, you end up back with the original JSON object still as a (stringified) string.  It's the same principle as double urlencoding but then single decoding.

Comment: @CrayonViolent you are awesome too :D

Comment: Thanks! This helped with getting the correct JSON, but I still can't access any members of the JSON. I updated my question with the new code I am using and the error message I get

Comment: that's just because there is no "json" item in sessionStorage